# why nginx logs are not written to default-error.log?

Tags: nginx, debian

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/default-proxy:**

```
server {
    listen xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:80 default_server;
    proxy_read_timeout 200s;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/default-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/default-error.log;

    include static.conf;

    location / {
        root              /var/www/web/sites;
        try_files         /$host/ @default_host;
        proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:80;
        proxy_redirect    http://127.0.0.1:80/ /;
    }

    location @default_host {
        proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.2:80;
        proxy_redirect    http://127.0.0.2:80/ /;
    }

    location @mass_hosting {
        root              /var/www/web/sites;
        try_files         /$host/ @default_host;
        proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:80;
        proxy_redirect    http://127.0.0.1:80/ /;
    }
}

server {
    listen xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:443 ssl;
    server_name domain.ru;

    proxy_read_timeout 200s;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/default-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/default-error.log;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_certificate     /var/www/web/ssl/domain.ru.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/web/ssl/domain.ru.key;

    location / {
        root              /var/www/web/sites;
        try_files         /$host/ @default_host;
        proxy_pass        https://127.0.0.1:443;
        proxy_redirect    https://127.0.0.1:443/ /;
    }

    location @default_host {
        proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.2:443;
        proxy_redirect    http://127.0.0.2:443/ /;
    }

    location @mass_hosting {
        root              /var/www/web/sites;
        try_files         /$host/ @default_host;
        proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:443;
        proxy_redirect    http://127.0.0.1:443/ /;
    }
}
```

in the access-default.log file, the entries are normal, but the default-error.log  file is empty.Why?
p.s what is the easiest way to check if the problem is fixed? call 404 error and check the log again?

Comment: Just hit a request page which is not available, 404 error mean **page not found**.

Comment: ok, the problem still as relevant - error-default.log is empty

Answer (score 0):

- make sure to check your access.log for these missing 404 (this may happen due to error_page or try_files directives)
- make sure "log_not_found" is not set to "off"[1]
- make sure the upstreams you are using are not returning a response indicating a 404 while returning a 200 status code (this would then be logged as a 200 in the access-log)

[1] https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#log_not_found

Comment: access_log is ok -404 :
`xx.xxx.xx.xxx - - [03/Jun/2019:00:12:46 -0400] "GET /s111111111 HTTP/1.1" 404 3759 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/xx.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"`

I have an additional question : how do I know what to be in @mass_hosting and  @default_host ?